# Jersey overwriting a content-length I attempt to set with -1

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am streaming an `entity`, and know what the length of the `stream` will be.

I'm attempting to set the `Content-Length` header. Unfortunately, Jersey seems to be overwriting this with -1. Most browsers don't appear to care about this, except for Safari when playing videos.

My code:

```
StreamingOutput stream = os -> {
    download.execute(os, user);
}

response = Response
                .status(Response.Status.PARTIAL_CONTENT)
                .entity(stream)
                .header("Content-Range", rangeResponseHeader)
                .header("Content-Length", download.getContentRange().length())
                .type(download.getMimeType())
                .build();
```

Is there something I can do to force `Jersey` to output my asserted content length?